# USB Will not open : Input/Output Error

Tags: usb-drive

I am getting this error message

```
'/media/vincent/6212-D81B/O27m╝αÄ.?#g': Input/output error.
```

Whenever I am trying to access the USB. I am inexperienced with computers and new to Ubuntu but try my best.

Comment: Do you have any info on the usb that you want to access? Otherwise you can try to format it.

Comment: It looks like you've got an external hard disk that's corrupt, or defective.